# Shell script to match row number from one file and put it as comments in another file when match

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, scripting, file-descriptors

I have two files. The content of both files has dynamic and generated by the system when required.

The first file contains the meaning for specific row number as below :

```
head simdb.txt 
MSISDN
Account_ID
COSP_ID
Currency
Language
Home_Zone
SIM_PIN
Screening_PIN
Third_ParAnothercess_PIN
Cumulative_Incorrect_PIN
```

Other file contains the dynamic data as below

```
head subscriber.txt
0='917598936722' 4='ENG' 6='1234'
```

Output should be like :

```
0='917598936722'  //MSISDN
4='ENG'           //Language
6='1234'          //SIM_PIN
```

Question updated========

Adding to the above query, if subscriber.txt would have multiple lines then how can we have a script to print line first then it required output? For example, if we subscriber.txt file like below

```
head subscriber.txt
0='917598936722' 4='ENG' 6='1234'
0='919654680634' 4='ENG' 6='1234'
```

Then desired output be like :

```
0='917598936722' 4='ENG' 6='1234'

0='917598936722'  //MSISDN
4='ENG'           //Language
6='1234'          //SIM_PIN
```

=========================================

```
0='919654680634' 4='ENG' 6='1234'

0='919654680634'  //MSISDN
4='ENG'           //Language
6='1234'          //SIM_PIN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR
    {Arr[NR-1]=$0;
    next}
    {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    {split($i,a,"="); 
    print $i "    //"Arr[a[1]]}
    }'simdb.txt subscriber.txt
```

- read all the lines from simdb.txt and keep in array. Index starts from 0
- read the second file and check what is the value before equal symbol
- read the value from Arr and print it.

Comment: Due to the linebreak after `NR==FNR`, this would print all lines from the first file (and nothing else).  You also miss a space before the first filename.

Comment: Thanks Kamaraj. After implementing suggestion from Kusalananda, the command is working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
                   split($i, a, "=")
                   s[a[1]+1] = $i }; next }
     FNR in s { printf("%-20s//%s\n", s[FNR], $0) }' subscriber.txt simdb.txt
```

This first reads the fields in the shorter `subscriber.txt` file and assigns their values to an array `s`.  The `s` array is keyed on the number in front of `=` in each field (plus one).

When the `simdb.txt` file is read, a test is made on the line number in that file.  If that line number is a key in our array `s`, the desired output is created.  The output is done with `printf` and a formatting string that allocates 20 characters for a left-justified string (the data from `simdb.txt`) followed by `//` and the data saved from `subscriber.txt` for that particular row.

Output given the data in the question:

```
0='917598936722'    //MSISDN
4='ENG'             //Language
6='1234'            //SIM_PIN
```